# Use ternary operator in apply function in pandas dataframe, without grouping columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use ternary operator in the lambda function within `apply` function of `pandas` dataframe?

First of all, this code is from R/plyr, which is exactly what I want to get:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise, sum(ifelse(carb==4,1,0))/sum(ifelse(carb %in% c(4,1),1,0)))
```

in the above function, I can use `ifelse` function, R's ternary operator, to compute the resultant dataframe.

However, when I want to do the same in Python/pandas with the following code

```
mtcars.groupby(["cyl"]).apply(lambda x: sum(1 if x["carb"] == 4 else 0) / sum(1 if x["carb"] in (4, 1) else 0))
```

, the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So how can I compute and get the same dataframe as in R/plyr?

For your information, if I use the ternary operator without grouping the columns, such as

```
mtcars.apply(lambda x: sum(1 if x["carb"] == 4 else 0) / sum(1 if x["carb"] in (4, 1) else 0), axis=1)
```

, I can get the resultant dataframe for some reasons (but it's not what I wanted to do).

Thanks.

[Update]

Sorry, the original example is not a good one when it comes to the use of ternary operator, since it uses `1` and `0`, which can be used as a binary. So the updated R/plyr code is the following:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise, sum(ifelse(carb==4,6,3))/sum(ifelse(carb %in% c(4,1),8,4)))
```

Is it feasible to use the ternary operator in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code could be translated to this:

```
mtcars.groupby(["cyl"])['carb'].apply(lambda x: sum((x == 4).astype(float)) / sum(x.isin((4, 1))))
```

Toy example:

```
>>> mtcars = pd.DataFrame({'cyl':[8,8,6,6,6,4], 'carb':[4,3,1,5,4,1]})
>>> mtcars
   carb  cyl
0     4    8
1     3    8
2     1    6
3     5    6
4     4    6
5     1    4
>>> mtcars.groupby(["cyl"])['carb'].apply(lambda x: sum((x == 4).astype(float)) / sum(x.isin((4, 1))))
cyl
4      0.0
6      0.5
8      1.0
dtype: float64
```

**update**

In more complex case, you can use [numpy.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mtcars.groupby(["cyl"])['carb'].apply(lambda x: sum(np.where(x == 4,6,3).astype(float)) / sum(np.where(x.isin((4,1)),8,4)))
cyl
4      0.375
6      0.600
8      0.750
dtype: float64
```

Comment: you can also replace `(x == 4).astype(float)` with `(x == 4)*1` which, for large arrays has been a bit faster in my tests but I'm not sure how generalizable it is.

Comment: Thanks. But I just realized that my example in the original post was not a good example, since it can be done without caring about ternary operator at all because all it uses is `1` and `0`, which can be easily translated to `true/false` binary number. So I updated the original post. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `x['carb']` is a numpy array (or subclass).  In this case, `x['carb'] == 4` returns a boolean array.  `True` where the values equal 4, `False` otherwise.  This is a very handy feature of numpy, but it can be annoying in situations like these (because it is natural to expect the `==` operator to return a boolean result).

The trick is to call `.all()` on the result:

```
(x['carb'] == 4).all()
```

That will return `True` only if **all** the elements in `(x['carb'] == 4)` are `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas’ `apply()` applies on rows.  Therefore the ternary operator can be used as

```
df.apply(lambda row: [1 if x>0 else 0 for x in row])
```

On OP’s example :

```
mtcars.groupby(["cyl"])['carb'].apply(lambda r: sum([1 if x==4 else 0 for x in r])/sum([1 if x in [1,4] else 0 for x in r]))
```

(This example might need a catch on division by zero, though…)